# Can we get Persistent Volume with only PVC (without PV) in k8s?

Tags: kubernetes, persistent-volumes, persistent-volume-claims

I just saw a yaml file for Postgres with `PersistentVolumeClaim` and `volumeMounts` and `volumes` with the `persistentVolumeClaim` in the `postgres` container. I couldn't find any `PersistentVolume` defined.

However, when the `postgres` container pod has been brought up, I can see a 
`PersistentVolume` bound to the `persistentVolumeClaim` defined in the yaml file.

So will k8s create the `PersistentVolume` if we only define the `PersistentVolumeClaim`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

yea that's correct, so when your cluster has dynamic provisioning with  [storage-classes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/storage-classes/) then you just need to provide the [PVC](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#persistentvolumeclaim) , provisioner will get relevant information from PVC and storageClass, then based on these info it will create the PV.

- Provisioning of PV happens  dynamically

  > When none of the static PVs the administrator created matches a user’s PersistentVolumeClaim, the cluster may try to dynamically provision a volume specially for the PVC. This provisioning is based on StorageClasses: the PVC must request a storage class and the administrator must have created and configured that class in order for dynamic provisioning to occur.
  >   [dynamic-provisining](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#dynamic)

For example here you provide the following info in PVC

1. StorageClassName
2. Requested Storage size
3. AccessModes

```
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: task-pv-claim
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 3Gi
```

In the StorageClass you provide the following information

1. Provisioner
2. Other information

```
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  name: manual
provisioner: kubernetes.io/aws-ebs
parameters:
  type: gp2
reclaimPolicy: Retain
volumeBindingMode: Immediate
```

- PVC is a namespace scoped kubernetes object but storageclass in a cluster scope k8s object. So there is always a default storageclass in your cluster.so when you do not specify the name of the storgaeclass in your pvc, PV will be provisioned from the  default storage class.

`kubectl get sc,pvc,pv` will provide the relevant information

Answer (score 12):

Actually, It has been done by

> **Dynamic provisioning of PersistentVolumes**.

**PersistentVolumes** and **PersistentVolumeClaims** makes it easy to obtain persistent storage without the developer having to deal with the actual storage technology used underneath. But this still requires a cluster administrator to **provision**  the  actual  storage  up  front. You think, **PersistentVolumes** have to been created, but It don't has to be like that all time. Luckily,  Kubernetes  can  also  perform  this  job automatically through **dynamic provisioning of PersistentVolumes.**

The cluster admin, instead of creating PersistentVolumes, can deploy a **PersistentVolume provisioner** and define one or more **StorageClass** objects to let users choose what type of **PersistentVolume** they want. The users can refer to the **StorageClass** in their  **PersistentVolumeClaims**  and  the  provisioner  will  take  that  into  account  when provisioning the persistent storage.

The kubernetes make it get simplier by including default **StoregeClass** definitions. You don't have to point a **StorageClass** in the yaml manifest like the following:

**The PVC yaml file:**

```
apiVersion: v1 
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim 
metadata:   
  name: postgresdb-pvc  
spec:   
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi   
   accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
```

*This  PVC  definition  includes  only  the  storage  size  request  and  the  desired  accessmodes,  but  no  storage  class*.  When  you  create  the  PVC,  whatever  storage  class  is marked as default will be used.

```
$ kubectl get pvc postgresdb-pvc

NAME            STATUS   VOLUME         CAPACITY   ACCESSMODES   STORAGECLASS
postgresdb-pvc  Bound    pvc-95a5ec12   1Gi        RWO           standard

$ kubectl get pv pvc-95a5ec12

NAME           CAPACITY  ACCESSMODES  RECLAIMPOLICY  STATUS    STORAGECLASS    
pvc-95a5ec12   1Gi       RWO          Delete         Bound     standard
```

This image that it is from [Kubernetes In Action](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1617293725) book, summarize all steps, perfectly.

[image]